# TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str, facing this error in keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp, computer-vision

I am running a keras model, [LINK IS HERE](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/nl_image_search/). I have just changed the dataset for this model and when I run my model it throwing this error `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str`. As it's a image captioning model and the dataset is difficult for me to understand.
See the blow code and read also the location of the error.

```
`reduce_lr = keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
    monitor="val_loss", factor=0.2, patience=3
 )
 # Create an early stopping callback.
 early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
 monitor="val_loss", patience=5, restore_best_weights=True 
 )
 history = dual_encoder.fit(
 train_dataloader,
 epochs=num_epochs,
 #validation_data=val_dataloader,
 #callbacks=[reduce_lr, early_stopping],
 )
 print("Training completed. Saving vision and text encoders...")
 vision_encoder.save("vision_encoder")
 text_encoder.save("text_encoder")
 print("Models are saved.")


 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-31-745dd79762e6> in <module>()
      15 history = dual_encoder.fit(
      16     train_dataloader,
 ---> 17     epochs=num_epochs,
      18     #validation_data=val_dataloader,
      19     #callbacks=[reduce_lr, early_stopping],

  11 frames
  <ipython-input-26-0696c83bf387> in call(self, features, training)
      16         with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
      17             # Get the embeddings for the captions.
 ---> 18             caption_embeddings = text_encoder(features["caption"], training=training)
      19             #caption_embeddings = text_encoder(train_inputs, training=training)
      20         with tf.device("/gpu:1"):

  TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str'
```

The error is pointing to this location `caption_embeddings = text_encoder(features["caption"], training=training)`

Now I am confused, I don't  know whether this error is due to the data which I am passing to my model like this `history = dual_encoder.fit(train_dataloader)` OR this error is related to `caption_embeddings = text_encoder(features["caption"], training=training)` and `image_embeddings = vision_encoder(features["image"], training=training)` which is defined in `class DualEncoder`.

Because I don't know what are these `features["caption"]` and `features["image"]` which is defined in `Class DualEncoder` as I have not changed these two with my new dataset if You check my [CODE HERE IN THIS COLAB FILE](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wjmlb2hx-VSMhRTYOQ2jTmBlR1KcuBs8?usp=sharing).

Comment: *complete* traceback please. that looks like ipython only shows the first and last one. that's not debuggable. please review [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataset (`train_dataloader`) seems to return a tuple of items: [link](https://github.com/coursat-ai/MultiCheXNet/blob/master/data_loader/indiana_dataloader.py#L161). In particular, model input is a tuple (`images`, `x_batch_input`).

However, your code (in DualEncoder) seems to assume that it's a dict (with keys like "caption", "image", etc). I think that's the source of the mismatch.

Comment: Thank You for your answer, Can I change `class DualEncoder` in such a wat that it accepts a tuple data?